# Wait until jquery function completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an `iframe` in my page and I am changing its `src` attribute using jquery, the problem is that I want to wait until the iframe is loaded then I need to call some other functions. Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content">
    <iframe name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
            src="pages/page1.jsp"></iframe>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#mainFrame').attr('src','pages/page2.jsp'); // wait until the iframe is loaded
$('#myTable').html('some stuff'); // then call this
```

**Note:** The `#myTable` element is present in both pages, so when I call this piece of code, it is changing the content of `#myTable` in `page1`, then changing the `src` of the iframe.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umYkV/)**

Will work:

```
 $('#mainFrame').attr('src','pages/page2.jsp'); 
 $('#Myiframe').load(function(){
    $('#myTable').html('some stuff'); // then call this
 });
```

Will Not work:

```
 $( "#mainFrame" ).load( "pages/page2.jsp", function() {
   $('#myTable').html('some stuff');
 });
```

And for if iframe url is from same domain.for accesing inner contents of iframe, you should use:

```
$('#Myiframe').contents().html('somestuff')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the .load function and place the subsequent functions in the callback:

```
$( "#mainFrame" ).load( "pages/page2.jsp", function() {
  $('#myTable').html('some stuff');
});
```